# I tried adding markers to google maps after receiving points from firebase. The code runs but new markers don't get displayed

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps

My fragment contains map and a searchView where user enters product name. After selecting the product name from suggestions, I want to add the markers to the map. Since there are multiple requests being sent to firebase, I receive product locations multiple times asynchronously (since it is a network call). I want to add markers asynchronously to my map in the fragment.

Inside `onMapReady` I have already stored the `googleMap` inside another variable `map` outside the function. After receiving locations from firebase I tried adding those markers using `map` variable but it didn't display new markers and app didn't crash either.

I'm using this function to add the new markers to my `map` variable.

```
private void addShopsLatnLong(List<String> shopsList) {
    newPoints = true;
    if (shopsList.size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "addshops called");
        FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        for (String shopId : shopsList) {
            firestore.collection(constants.getOwner()).document(shopId)
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
                        Profile profile = documentSnapshot.toObject(Profile.class);
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(profile.getLatitude(),profile.getLongitude())));
                        Log.d(TAG, "points " + profile.getLatitude() + " " + profile.getLongitude());
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.d(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm assigning value to my `map` variable.

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady called");
        runnable= () -> {
            for (LatLng latLng : locationArrayList) {
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("new!!"));
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }
        };
        if (newPoints) {
            Log.d(TAG, "size for new points - " + locationArrayList.size());
            for (LatLng latLng : locationArrayList) {
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("new!!"));
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }
        } else {
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            constants = new FiresStoreTableConstants();
            final String email = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
            firebaseFirestore.collection(constants.getCustomer()).document(email)
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                            Profile profile = documentSnapshot.toObject(Profile.class);
                            Log.d(TAG, "profile:" + profile);
                            LatLng you = new LatLng(profile.getLatitude(), profile.getLongitude());
                            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(you).title("You!!"));
                            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(you));
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> e.printStackTrace());
        }
    }
```

## What I tried -

- I created a runnable which would be responsible for adding new markers and then assigned it's value inside `onMapReady`.(Since that didn't work I tried other options and hence the entire logic isn't present here.
- I tried using LiveData to assign markers that didn't work either.

## Just in case you want the entire code here it is -

```
package com.example.ec_geocustomer;

import static androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.MotionEffect.TAG;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter;
import androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;

import com.example.ec_geocustomer.data.FiresStoreTableConstants;
import com.example.ec_geocustomer.data.Profile;
import com.example.ec_geocustomer.databinding.FragmentSearchViewBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class SearchViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private static String barcode;
    FragmentSearchViewBinding binding;
    boolean newPoints = false;
    ArrayList<LatLng> locationArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
//    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<LatLng>> testLive = new MutableLiveData<>(new ArrayList<>());
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    LatLng TamWorth = new LatLng(-31.083332, 150.916672);
    LatLng NewCastle = new LatLng(-32.916668, 151.750000);
    LatLng Brisbane = new LatLng(-27.470125, 153.021072);
    HashMap<String, String> list = new HashMap<>();
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore, fStore;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FiresStoreTableConstants constants;
    List<String> ShopsList;
    String itemBarcodeSearched = null;

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    GoogleMap map;

    Runnable runnable;
    private final OnMapReadyCallback callback = new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
            map = googleMap;
            Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady called");
            runnable= () -> {
                for (LatLng latLng : locationArrayList) {
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("new!!"));
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                }
            };
            if (newPoints) {
                Log.d(TAG, "size for new points - " + locationArrayList.size());
                for (LatLng latLng : locationArrayList) {
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("new!!"));
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                }
            } else {
                firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                constants = new FiresStoreTableConstants();
                final String email = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                firebaseFirestore.collection(constants.getCustomer()).document(email)
                        .get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                Profile profile = documentSnapshot.toObject(Profile.class);
                                Log.d(TAG, "profile:" + profile);
                                LatLng you = new LatLng(profile.getLatitude(), profile.getLongitude());
                                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(you).title("You!!"));
                                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(you));
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(e -> e.printStackTrace());
            }
        }
    };
    private boolean isSuggestionClicked = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        testLive.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), latLngs -> {
//            try{
//                runnable.run();
//                Log.d(TAG,"runnable executed");
//            }catch(Exception e){
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            };
//
//        });
        binding = FragmentSearchViewBinding.bind(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_view, container, false));
        // get itemnames
        FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FiresStoreTableConstants constants = new FiresStoreTableConstants();
        firebaseFirestore.collection(constants.getBarcode())
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : documents) {
                        list.put(documentSnapshot.getId(), documentSnapshot.getString(constants.getBarcodeName()));
                    }
                });
        //set suggestion adapter
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.searchItemID};
        String[] from = new String[]{SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1};
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.suggestion_list, null, from, to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        binding.searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if (isSuggestionClicked) {
                    // get barcode of item clicked
                    Log.d(TAG, "isSuggestion clicked !");
                    barcode = getBarcode(query);
                    if (barcode != null) {
                        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        ShopsList = new ArrayList<>();
                        fStore.collection(constants.getOwner())
                                .get()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                        //TODO: 23-02-2023 get list of shops
                                        List<DocumentSnapshot> ids = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                                        Log.d(TAG, "OWNER IDS " + ids.size());
                                        for (DocumentSnapshot id : ids) {
                                            fStore.collection(constants.getOwner()).document(id.getId()).collection(constants.getOwnerAvailability())
                                                    .whereGreaterThan(constants.getOwnerQuantity(), 0)
                                                    .get()
                                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                                            List<DocumentSnapshot> barcodeList = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                                                            for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : barcodeList) {
                                                                if (documentSnapshot.getId().equals(barcode)) {
                                                                    ShopsList.add(id.getId());
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                            addShopsLatnLong(ShopsList);
                                                            Log.d(TAG, "List of shops:" + ShopsList);
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(e -> e.printStackTrace());
                        newPoints = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select products from suggestion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                binding.searchView.clearFocus();
                onViewCreated(binding.getRoot(), savedInstanceState);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // suggestions from firebase
                MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{
                        BaseColumns._ID, SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1
                });
                ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>(list.values());
                for (int j = 0; j < valueList.size(); j++) {
                    if (valueList.get(j).toLowerCase().startsWith(newText.toLowerCase()))
                        cursor.addRow(new Object[]{j, valueList.get(j)});
                }
                cursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
                return false;
            }
        });

        binding.searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
                Cursor cursor1 = (Cursor) cursorAdapter.getItem(position);
                @SuppressLint("Range") String item = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1));
                isSuggestionClicked = true;
                binding.searchView.setQuery(item, true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    private void addShopsLatnLong(List<String> shopsList) {
        newPoints = true;
        if (shopsList.size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "addshops called");
            FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

            for (String shopId : shopsList) {
                firestore.collection(constants.getOwner()).document(shopId)
                        .get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
                            Profile profile = documentSnapshot.toObject(Profile.class);
//                            ArrayList<LatLng> temp = testLive.getValue();
//                            temp.add(new LatLng(profile.getLatitude(), profile.getLongitude()));
//                            testLive.setValue(temp);
                            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(profile.getLatitude(),profile.getLongitude())));
                            Log.d(TAG, "points " + profile.getLatitude() + " " + profile.getLongitude());
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.d(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
    }

    private String getBarcode(String query) {
        //get barcode
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : list.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().trim().equals(query.trim())) {
                itemBarcodeSearched = entry.getKey();
                return itemBarcodeSearched;
            }
        }
        return itemBarcodeSearched;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(callback);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400** (four hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).